# CSS Image Positioning, akin to background-position

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have really big images that I want to fit into a height of `500px` and also be *nearly* centered horizontally and vertically. They are not background images, so I can't use the `background-position` property. I think I need something like this, but for img tags:

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

**Edit:** I need the width to be `100%`. I'm trying to make this work with the "Better Simple Slideshow." Here is the codepen link to that: http://tinyurl.com/k38oapk.

Comment: why don't you use a container <div width="500" style="text-align:center;"><img src="" /></div>?

Comment: I need the width to be 100%. I'm trying to make this work with the "Better Simple Slideshow": http://codepen.io/leemark/pen/mwoHj

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is the object-fit property in this case. You can read about it on the Mozilla MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

This is an example from the MDN. The HTML markup:

```
<div>
  <h2>object-fit: contain</h2>
  <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="MDN Logo" class="contain"/>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick. Is it as simple as adding "object-fit: contain;" to css for the tinyurl (aka codepen) link I mentioned in the initial post?

Comment: @DanielN That's the only way I can see you can do it. Otherwise, you have to change your markup to work with the background property.